# Chrome is not picking up CSS media queries when using optimisations in bundles

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, media-queries, bundling-and-minification

As I have mentioned in the title - chrome is not picking up the media queries. For example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 784px)
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 784px)
```

It works if I leave only one width property:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px)
```

All other browsers picks this up ok. Did anyone of you came to this issue as well and can help   me to get on track?

**Edit**

I'm using the latest version of chrome (Version 32.0.1700.76 m)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in chrome where it won't read media queries without the correct spacing. If you look at your bundled source code (when minified) you will probably notice that `@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 784px)` has been transformed to `@media (min-width: 481px)and (max-width: 784px)` (**notice the missing space after the bracket**).

[This article](http://i-skool.co.uk/net/mvc/mvc-bundling-and-minifcation-issues-with-google-chrome/) explains the problem well and also a fix which is basically to create a class that implements `IBundleTransform` and implement `Process` at which point you can check for this problem and fix it:

```
public class CssMinifyMQ : IBundleTransform {
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response) {
        response.ContentType = "text/css";
        response.Content = Regex.Replace(response.Content, "(\\) and ( )?\\()", ") and (");
    }
}

bundles.Add(
    new Bundle("~/CSS/Base", new CssMinifyMQ()).Include("~/Content/Base/*.css")
);
```

HTH!

Comment: Wonderful find and answer!